# Need $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $f$ is not convex but $f(x^p)$ is for $p>1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, convex-analysis

To be more specific I need to find an $f:[0,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$ which satisfies the following:

(somewhat trivial stuff) The function $f$ is continuous, nondecreasing, there exists $k>0$ such that $f(2k)\leq kf(x)$ for all $x\in[0,\infty)$ ($\Delta_2$-condition), $f(x)=0\iff x=0$ and $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

(the real issue) For every $p>1$ there exists $g_p:[0,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$, a number $x_p\in[0,+\infty)$ and two constants $0<c_p<C_p<\infty$ such that $g_p$ is convex on $(x_p,\infty)$ and $c_pg_p(x)\leq f(x^p)\leq C_pg_p(x)$ for $x\in(x_p,\infty)$ (so $f$ and $g_p$ are equivalent at $\infty$).  However, I need $f$ itself to not be convex.

Heuristically speaking, it's almost like we want "$f(x)=x^r$ for the largest $r$ in $(0,1)$."  I've tried a great deal of functions and I simply can't get it to work out.  I've tried $e$ to function powers, $x$ to function powers, I've thrown logs in, but something always messes up.  It seems really simple but I just can't seem to get it.  Or perhaps there is no such function.

I asked a question somewhat similar to this a while ago ([Need an $ f $ so that $ 0 < -\left(f'(x) + \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}\right) < \epsilon/x $ and $ e^{f(x)}/x \stackrel{x \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298190/need-an-f-so-that-0-leftfx-fracfxfx-right-epsilo)), but now I have a more refined version.  I actually think the old one had no answer (that is, there was no such function).

Comment: Have you checked $f(x) = x / log(x+2)$ or something like that?

Comment: It works!  In fact given any $p\in(1,\infty)$, $f(x^p)$ is itself convex for large $x$.  How elegant.  Much appreciated gerw.  Though I do feel silly for tinkering with it for so long and getting nothing.

Comment: No problem ;) $x / \log(x)$ often works, if one needs $x^r$ with the largest $r < 1$ ;)